# free почему то не удаляет массив из памяти

Tags: c

Обнаружил, что free почему то не удаляет массив из памяти. И когда я с помощью free удаляю 1 массив и потом с помощью malloc создаю другой, при создании новый массив указывает на часть старого массива, как это исправить?

Comment: Что, по-вашему, "удалить из памяти"? Он удален. А **затирать** вам никто не обещал - зачем?

Comment: Не удаляйте старый, новый будет в другом месте. Гарантия.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, хочется чтоб ненужные данные не висели в памяти

Comment: Это нормальное поведение. Если оно вам мешает, исправьте логику своей программы

Comment: Личные функции выделения памяти никто не отменял. Просто придумать архитектуру хранения, выделить большой кусок памяти, свой _malloc и свой _free. Где каждый _free будет гарантировать, что _malloc будет в другом месте.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, Зачем вы заставляете человека страдать *NIH синдромом*?! Можно же и без этого! Почитайте про *бритву Оккама*.

Comment: Это был намёк, чтобы человек не страдал этим синдромом. А пользовался тем, что есть. @0andriy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

malloc выделяет определенный объем памяти и гарантирует неполучение другими процессами (как и этим) этого куска памяти. Она не обнуляет хранилище, просто резервирует.
free снимает резерв с выделенного с помощью malloc-подобных функций.
То есть, после высвобождения с помощью free этим куском памяти могут пользоваться другие. Это и есть освобождение памяти, зачем в этот кусок записывать при это нули (или еще что?).

---

Для того, чтобы получить "свободную" память, воспользуйтесь calloc

Comment: `calloc()` тоже резервирует. В зависимостри от ОС там дальше происходят интересные хитрости. Была где-то замечательная статья на эту тему.

Comment: Разумеется, calloc() резервирует, просто заполняет память нулевыми байтами.

Comment: Не заполняет. В том-то и суть.

Comment: Локально вырубает электричество? Что она делает?

Comment: https://vorpus.org/blog/why-does-calloc-exist/ вот, нашёл. Почитайте, если интересно. Ключевые слова: zero page, copy-on-write.

Comment: Статья больше про особенности самой calloc по сравнению с malloc. То, что касается нашей темы: calloc знает, где существует нетронутая данным процессом, но выделенная под этот процесс и обнуленная, память. Ее он и берет. Да, с точки зрения быстродействия это важно. Но с точки зрения "свободной" памяти функция выделяет для тебя нулевую память.

Comment: Зависит от ОС. В разных может быть по-разному. Но многие ухитряются. Почитайте про zero page.